# SimpleMessageListenerContainer stop to consume from RabbitMQ when restart the primary node of RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

When RabbitMQ is configured to work as a cluster and the primary node is restarted then org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer can not recover and can not consume messages (from RabbitMQ).

spring-rabbit version: 1.3.3.RELEASE

RabbitMQ version: 3.3.1

When the primary node of the cluster is restarted then we get the following exception:

```
2014-10-03 17:36:00,136 [WARN] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1099): Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it 
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:715) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:705) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleConnectionClose(AMQConnection.java:660) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.processControlCommand(AMQConnection.java:615) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$1.processAsync(AMQConnection.java:107) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:540) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2014-10-03 17:36:00,136 [INFO] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1090): Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-5pEx0wJyFWB1DNqUlN_51w]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: PublisherCallbackChannelImpl: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5673/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 
2014-10-03 17:36:06,459 [WARN] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1099): Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it 
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:63) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:112) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:841) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:820) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:391) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:323) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:32) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:361) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:309) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:283) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:276) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$600(CachingConnectionFactory.java:69) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:614) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createChannel(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:134) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:363) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:779) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.queueDeclare(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:362) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:536) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.queueDeclare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:458) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$200(RabbitAdmin.java:54) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$12.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:395) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:835) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'hare@mbp15Q0F1G3' of durable queue 'myqueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'hare@mbp15Q0F1G3' of durable queue 'myqueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:478) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:315) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:550) ~[amqp-client-3.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
2014-10-03 17:36:06,460 [INFO] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1090): Restarting Consumer: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 
2014-10-03 17:36:06,465 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(446): Failed to declare queue:myqueue 
2014-10-03 17:36:06,466 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(388): Queue declaration failed; retries left=2 
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[myqueue]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2014-10-03 17:36:11,469 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(446): Failed to declare queue:myqueue 
2014-10-03 17:36:11,470 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(388): Queue declaration failed; retries left=1 
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[myqueue]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2014-10-03 17:36:16,475 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(446): Failed to declare queue:myqueue 
2014-10-03 17:36:16,475 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(388): Queue declaration failed; retries left=0 
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[myqueue]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) [spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2014-10-03 17:36:21,479 [WARN] BlockingQueueConsumer(446): Failed to declare queue:myqueue 
2014-10-03 17:36:21,480 [ERROR] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1026): Consumer received fatal exception on startup 
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.FatalListenerStartupException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:407) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[myqueue]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:449) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
2014-10-03 17:36:21,480 [ERROR] SimpleMessageListenerContainer(1085): Stopping container from aborted consumer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'hare@mbp15Q0F1G3' of durable queue 'myqueue' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible, class-id=50, method-id=10)

It sounds like you haven't configured the queue for HA - only [mirrored queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) are replicated.

Comment: I tested with a queue configured for HA, but I still get the same error.    I configured the cluster with the following command: rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "^ha\." '{"ha-mode":"all"}'.    And I created a queue (using spring-rabbit) named "ha.myqueue" but the consumers can not recover when restart the primary node :(

Comment: Did you check the state of the queue on the admin UI? It will show whether the queue is mirrored or not and which node is currently the home node.

Comment: Thanks! You are right! my queue was not configured for HA. Sorry for my misconfiguration.

Comment: hi martin... i am also facing the same issue can u help me??? my queue and all correctly configured with HA. Eventhough i facing that issue.....


[ WARN] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 04:48:05] (SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:logConsumerException:1097) Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException

Comment: You need to look further up the log for the cause (e.g. the 404 above); it is better to start a new question unless the problem is exactly the same. If the error __is__ a 404 then your queue is __not__ configured correctly.